How do I solve for s in this multivariable equation?
Just to preface this, it's been a long while since I've done any sort of algebra like this so please bear with me here - given the understanding that a sale price $s$ is how much a product is sold for, and the variables below:

$c$, a cost price (a fixed cost on on how much it costs to procure the product)
$t$, a threshold at which a percentage-based fee on $s$ changes (see below)
$f_0$, a percentage-based fee that applies on the portion of the sale price $s$ up to and including the threshold $t$ (similar to cost price, but its variable depending on $s$)
$f_1$, a percentage-based fee that applies on the portion of the sale price $s$ after the threshold $t$ (similar to cost price, but its variable depending on $s$)

I'm trying solve for $s$ that would yield a profit of $0$, where profit is the sale price minus the cost price and fees.
So for example: Given a cost price of \$112 ($c=112$), a 15% fee ($f_0=0.15$) on the sale price up to \$100 ($t=100$), and a \$10% fee ($f_1=0.10$) on the sale price after \$100, find the sale price $s$ at which the product can be sold for a profit of $0$.
My goal is to try to create a function of the 4 aforementioned variables (if it's even possible) so that I can write a program for it, but this has been hard to wrap my head around. After recalling anything I can possibly remember from my school days, I think I came down to the equation below after some trial and error for the above example at least to calculate a profit of $0$:
$s-0.15(min(s,100))-0.10(max(s-100,0))-112 = p$ where $p=0$
and this seems to work since Wolfram Alpha is able to solve for $s=130$ - but is this really correct? Trying to use various online solvers (including Wolfram Alpha) to solve for $s$ below:
$s-f_0(min(s,t))-f_1(max(s-t,0))-c = 0$
causes them to all fail which casts some doubt. I'm a bit lost on whether this is even basic algebra or something more complex so any help here would be greatly appreciated

By "fee", do you mean a discount on sale price ? Can you pl. clarify what you neab by a "fee" on sales price ?

@trueblueanil sorry for the confusion, I've updated it now. The fee is similar to the cost price, but instead of being a fixed number, it is variable - dependent on the sale price. All costs (cost price and percentage-based fees) are subtracted from the sale price to calculate the profit

You're exactly right. The net fees are indeed $f_0 \min(s,t) + f_1 \max(s-t,0),$ and so the equation you have, $$ s = f_0 \min(s,t) + f_1\max(s-t, 0) + c,$$ is correct. The trouble with solving this automatically is that the RHS of the equation is a piecewise function, which automated solvers can have difficulty dealing with. However, we can solve it directly in two pieces.
First, if there was a solution with $s \le t,$ then we'd have $$ s = f_0 s + c \iff s = c/(1-f_0). $$ Of course, we'd have to check that this number is less than $t$ (which it may not be), in which case there's no solution in $(-\infty, t]$. In other words, this solution is valid only if $c/(1-f_0) \le t \iff c \le (1-f_0) t$.
On the other hand, if there was a solution with $s > t,$ then we'd have the equation $$ s = (f_0 - f_1) t + c + f_1 s \iff s = \frac{c + (f_0 - f_1)t}{1-f_1}.$$ Again for this to be valid, we need $(c + (f_0 - f_1)t)(1-f_1) \ge t,$ which holds if and only if $c \ge (1-f_0) t$ (verify this).
Happily, the two conditions on $(c,f_0,t)$ in order to generate solutions are complementary, and so we find that there is always a unique zero profit point. We can write this in a piecewise form to get $$ s = \begin{cases} \frac{c}{1-f_0} &  \textrm{ if $c \le (1-f_0)t,$} \\  \frac{c + (f_0 - f_1) t}{1-f_1} &\textrm{ if $c > (1-f_0) t$} \end{cases}.$$
You can translate this to a $\max() + \min()$ form if you desire, I'll leave that to you.

For the example data $c = 112, t = 100, f_0 = 0.15, f_1 = 0.1,$ we get $$ c = 112 > 0.85  \times 100 = (1-f_0)t,$$ and so the first solution is invalid, but the second solution is valid, which you can compute to find $s = 130$.
If instead we had, e.g., $c = 80,$ then since $80 <  0.85 \times 100,$ the first solution would be valid and the second invalid.

This is really really good - it never occurred to me to simplify the min/max in that way (I instead expanded it to their absolute-notation equivalents which evidently just made things more complicated), and the equivalencies helped light up some bulbs. Thank you!

You're welcome. Btw, wolfram alpha does actually give a solution to the above, just that it is messy and has too many cases. I'm sure that with some patience you could extract the above solution from this output, though.

Interesting - it looks like I hadn't given it the right prompt then since it was taking too long to the point it gave up. Good to know though, thanks

So adopting your notation of $c,s,f_0,f_1$, the equation should simply be
$s = c+ 100\cdot f_0 + (s-100)\cdot f_1$
with $f_0,f_1$ in decimal fractions, e.g. $15\% =0.15$
For a cost price of $112$, e.g. you correctly got that the sales price should be $130$ for zero profit
The equation can perhaps be better expressed as
$s = \dfrac {c+100(f_0=f_1)}{(1-f_1)}$

Is it possible to isolate $s$ so that it is only on one side of the equation? So that it is a function of $c$, $t$, $f0$ and $f1$ - I believe that's what I'm trying to see whether or not it's possible

Ok,  I will add, you seem to be very rusty in Algebra now !

Yeah sorry about that - I've spent a week on this and I think most of my trouble is coming from that fact that it needs to be a function of 4 variables (so the $100$ is replaced with $t$) - if the steps on how the solution was achieved is also available, that would greatly help my learning process here

It's ok, I am also very rusty in very many areas, have added.

Thank you! I tested the answer with $c=80$, $f_0=0.15$ and $f_1=0.1$ and it looks like it's giving a sale price that yields a non-zero profit ($0.2777778$) though - this seems to make sense given what stochasticboy321 mentioned which is that it is a piecewise function

It can't be, see here, the answer should be $94.44$

Right, that is the sale price $s$, but if I try to calculate the profit using that sale price: $94.44 - 80 - .15(94.44)=0.277$ (roughly) rather than $0$

The equation I gave applies only if $s>100$ (or $c>85$) so that both $f_0$ and $f_1$ come into the picture. For lower values than that, $s = c+100f_0$
